# A Vue.js component is not being compiled by webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

So I've been trying for weeks now to get a custom component to compile and it is not working. I know it isn't compiling becuause when I check the compiled Vue file, I search for the custom element added. It does not appear in the compiled JavaScript.

The funny thing is is that the ExampleComponent.vue file gets compiled. However, every time I try to add a custom Vue component file, my JavaScript console tells me that the custom element is not defined. Like I said, I searched my compiled JS file and I see nothing whenI search for the name of my custom element.

I have tried using several methods to import the vue file but it still never gets compiled. I don't know thatI'm doing wrong.

Here is my ChatMessage.vue file

```
    <template>
    <div class="container">
    <P>I'm an example message</P>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my app.js file

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

and here is my view

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title goes here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <h1>Chatroom</h1>
    <example-component>

    </example-component>

    <chat-message><</chat-message>

</div>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Here is my webpack.mix.js file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for your application, as well as bundling up your JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', '/public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/scss/stylesheet.scss', '/public/css');

// Full API
// mix.js(src, output);
// mix.extract(vendorLibs);
// mix.sass(src, output);
// mix.less(src, output);
// mix.combine(files, destination);
// mix.copy(from, to);
// mix.minify(file);
// mix.sourceMaps(); // Enable sourcemaps
// mix.version(); // Enable versioning.
// mix.disableNotifications();
// mix.setPublicPath('path/to/public'); <-- Useful for Node apps.
// mix.webpackConfig({}); <-- Override webpack.config.js, without editing the file directly.
```

Comment: here: `<chat-message><</chat-message>` you have two characters: `<<`

Comment: How did you create this application?  Did you use `vue-cli`?

Comment: How do you complie .vue files-  webpack or gulp or something?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and removed the extra <. Still no luck. I created this application by hand. I hard-coded the .Vue file. In other words I created the Vue file by hand.

Comment: I compile my files with Webpack

Comment: This seemed to me like a Laravel project. Can you post your `webpack.mix.js`?

Comment: Just edited my original question with the code you asked for.

Comment: This is so weird. Everything that you have posted seemed to be normal and should work. I cannot spot anything unusual.

Comment: Do you think if I use Yarn it will make a difference? I've been following my YouTube tutorials closely and nothing seems to be working

Comment: you say that only one component is compiled in output js file - so what is the difference? what if you switch sequence of components?

Comment: I tired what you suggested and all I get is the same output as before. I stil lget the example component when I try to switch it out for something else.

Comment: @TomMorison I reckon this has nothing to do with `npm` or `yarn`. I really cannot spot anything unless I pull your project and run it through. If you do not mind, upload your code to Github?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/TomMorison12/cryptoflip

Comment: Sorry to necropost, but did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue. Weirdest thing is that I'm using the component all over the app and there's only one place where this happens...

Answer (score 0):

You should use vue compiler with mix.

Try placing .vue() in your Mix

```
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', '/public/js/app.js')
       .sass('resources/assets/scss/stylesheet.scss', '/public/css').vue();
```